# VDSL service from BSNL India - modem & wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, modem, vdsl

I'm just now ordering VDSL internet service from BSNL India, and they are not giving me much help on modems / wireless routers.  They don't seem to offer any equipment for rent or sale with this service, so it looks like it's up to me. I'm digging for more tech support from them but right now I've gotten the "whatever you choose will work" line, which I know is not true because ADSL and VDSL modems are not compatible (as I understand it).

I know I need a VDSL modem or all-in-one modem and wireless router that supports VDSL/2. I've found some from D-Link and Linksys, but none that are available in India. I'll also be administering it from a Mac, so I do want something with a decent web interface or (less-preferable) Mac software. So, my questions are:

1. Once I find a VDSL modem, assuming it's not an all-in-one, then I will need a wireless router that supports more than 1Mbps upstream speeds, as my plan (supposedly) offers 10Mbps down and 4Mbps up.

   - all-in-one modem + wireless routers, like the D-Link DSL-2750U WIRELESS N ADSL2+ 4-PORT WI-FI ROUTER, is first of all ADSL2+ and second of all advertises upload speeds of just 1Mbps, so this isn't going to broadcast the speed my service is giving me, isn't that correct?
   - will a 300Mbps wireless router easily transmit the upstream speeds of 4Mbps that my service provider is giving me? I presume it will, but I'm still not clear on the download/upload speeds and what the advertised speed actually means.
   - or should I consider a 600Mbps or above?
   - I'll connect my main work computer via ethernet straight to the router, so will Gigabit ethernet make the internet connection snappier or is 10/100 way faster than the service anyway and I wouldn't feel any difference?

Comment: Super User doesn't do product recommendations; I've edited out the bits which seek the recommendation

Answer (score 2):

If you want an integrated solution the best available seems to be :
asus dsl-n66u. Note the dsl tag, there is also rt-n66u which is only wifi no vdsl. This box is expensive but seems to be very good as well. 
The other solution is to get a separate vdsl modem and a wifi router. Note that there are hardly any single box wifi ac + vdsl solutions out there. I am on the look out for such a solution.

With regards to N600 vs N900 etc:
If you are only going to use this to connect to net, no point in going for high speed wifi router.
If you have an extensive home network and want to do things like stream media wirelessly to your tv or tablet from a usb disk connected directly to your router then you should definitely go for  N900 if not wifi ac.

Comment: Thanks much! BSNL has subsequently said they can't deliver VDSL service to my location after all, so I'm stuck with ADSL for the moment, with very poor upload speeds (.65 Mbps max at the moment). I'll certainly look into the asus if/when they are able to provide VDSL service. I do some high speed transfer, but not to a smart TV, so probably I don't need maximum speed. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

I too am a BSNL subscriber and did upgrade from an ADSL to a VDSL plan. Upon calling them and asking them about whether the modem needs to be changed, they told me that none of the modems that were provided as part of the FTTH (Fiber-To-the-Home) plan needs to be changed (my previous plan was FTTH too, albeit much slower - 4Mbps upto 30GB and 1Mbps after). The new plan is supposed to be: 40Mbps upto 100GB and 4Mbps after.

The upgrade supposedly came through yesterday, and I now get 4Mbps down and ~40Mbps up (yeah, weird). But that could be because I was above the FUP limit in the old plan, when I upgraded (up until the day before, I was at 1Mbps). I am not yet very sure, but it does looks like VDSL is working (due to the 40Mbps uplink).

The modem I have currently (provided by BSNL for my old connection) is the AONT-100C. Is this what you have?

[AONT-100C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plm5q.jpg)

A first reading gives the impression that the 100C (part of the 1000 series) does not support VDSL+2. I am not very sure, but a closer look at it, it seems like the 1k, 2k & 3k series only differ in capacities. i.e., 1k for homes, 3k at a hub, etc. So maybe, they are all VDSL capable.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: I know. I am contending the premise of the question.

Comment: The OP has said "BSNL has subsequently said they can't deliver VDSL service to my location after all".

Comment: True, but that was two years ago. Maybe they are doing so now.

Comment: The link in the answer is broken.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks; Looks like they've removed it, and any info on that model. I'm changing the link to an image.